# Everytime I make a change in the designer the file copies the dataset with an extension C#

Tags: c#, dataset

Every time I make a change to the design of one of my files and hit compile it encounters an error with the datasets saying 'The type or namespace does not exist' as shown below.

[image]

However, when I delete the extension Easybase, it seems to work.

[image]

This is fine and works when I compile but every time I make a change to the designer, it adds the 'Easybase.' extension back on and the error occurs once again.

I have tried moving the file from directory to directory, I've deleted the file several times but for some reason, this issue still occurs.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, please.

Comment: Create a new project without any unneeded packages or references and create what I'm guessing is a TableAdapter and see if that works.